# Declaration is only valid at file scope Error SWIFT app project

Tags: swift, xcode

I am very new to coding apps, and have been trying to figure things out along the way, but I can't seem to find an answer for my code in swift. I think I formatted something wrong but don't know what. Here is a picture to hopefully help you understand:[This image shows the error message and all code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yshFl.png)

Here is the code. The error saying "declaration is only valid at file scope" occurs on the line with the code:

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {                     



    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
            scrollView.delegate = self
        }
        @IBAction func randomWord(_ sender: Any) {
            let array = ["Dam", "Military Base", "Quarry", "Airport", "Tv Station", "Storage Town", "Superstore", "Stadium", "Lumber", "Boneyard", "Train Station", "Hospital", "Downtown", "Farmland", "Promenade East", "Promenade West", "Hills", "Park", "Port", "Prison"]
            label.text = array.randomElement()
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
        @IBOutlet weak var mapImage: UIImageView!
        extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {                            
            func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
                return mapImage
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Move your extension out of your view controller

Comment: hey! Thanks for the response. Im an absolute noob though, I'm 14 and just been watching YouTube videos and trying to learn from there. I did what you said I think except now there is another problem, which says, "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UIScrollViewDelegate'." Here is the new snippet of code (The error is on the second to last bracket):                                                                      var ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return mapImage
        }
    }
}

Comment: please edit your question and update your code

Comment: Sorry, just did. Accidentally pressed the return key and it finished the comment lol

Comment: Sorry you can't move it out of your view controller

Comment: just move your method back to the view controller without the extension line

Comment: Here is an image link that may help more :)

Comment: https://ibb.co/CzjCxML

Comment: Lol what does that mean to move my method back to view controller?

Comment: don't post screen shots

Comment: k sorry I won't post anymore screenshots

Comment: func ViewController() -> UIScrollViewDelegate {
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return mapImage
        }
    }
}

Comment: that is what it looks like now, the format is a little weird but it still gives a, "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UIScrollViewDelegate'" error

Comment: so just remove `extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {` and the closing bracket `}` after the `viewForZooming`  method

Comment: Broooo no way it works now! Thats sick! Thank you so much! No errors! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer. If you don't know how to mark an answer as correct let me know

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make your method an instance method of your view controller:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction func randomWord(_ sender: Any) {
        let array = ["Dam", "Military Base", "Quarry", "Airport", "Tv Station", "Storage Town", "Superstore", "Stadium", "Lumber", "Boneyard", "Train Station", "Hospital", "Downtown", "Farmland", "Promenade East", "Promenade West", "Hills", "Park", "Port", "Prison"]
        label.text = array.randomElement()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapImage: UIImageView!
    // make viewForZooming a an instance method of ViewController
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return mapImage
    }
}
```